# Android: drawbacks of using no themes

Tags: android, themes

Suppose I elect to choose my own colors for everything, at the risk of being not entirely fitting to surrounding apps.

My worry is that even if I select `None` as my theme in Eclipse, I still get some default themes:

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>
</resources>
```

**res/values-v14/styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>
</resources>
```

My question is: If my colors seem after all more or less harmonious on Android, do I have to be worried if I delete AppBaseTheme and AppTheme from `styles.xml`, as well as delete `android:theme` in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO you don't. Every android device has a default theme based on the installed version and on the manufacturer.

For example, create a layout with a progressbar and with no style and themes at all then run the app in an emulator with api 10 and in another one with api 17. You will see the difference in the design because of the default theme used. The same thing happens if for example your app is targeting api 10 and runs on a device with higher api, the styles of the app will be from api 10.

If you miss something in your custom styling then that something will be designed based on the default theme of the api your app is targeting. This may lead to poor user experience besides the ugliness. Furthermore in newer versions of android there are some ui elements (like action bar) that they only work based on platform styles and themes and that is your biggest risk (IMHO).

Bottom line is that if you don't care about the styling then let android handle everything by not deleting the style and themes references from your res and manifest. If you want to style everything yourself then your best road to success is to follow the styling system that android offers and override the attributes to create your own styling.

Hope this helps...

P.S. Keep in mind that styling isn't only the colors, there are a lot of other things (like dimensions, states list, animations, drawables, 9 patches e.t.c.) that you have to take in consideration when you create your own styles...

Comment: In other words, you are pointing out that whether I like it or not, I am using themes. If I omit any mention of themes in my code, and define all attributes myself (colors, dimensions, etc..), then I will still be using the default theme of the platform. Hence if my objective is to control every aspect of the user experience, then I'm better off actually adopting a theme and overriding what I want, rather than omitting themes altogether.

Comment: @Calaf You are absolutely right! And it is not that hard as it seems to be, however it is a LOT of work, for example it took me nearly an hour just to style the checkbox the way I wanted because I had to create 15 drawables for it...

Comment: My dilemma is this. If I inherit, say, Holo.Light.DarkActionBar, I do not see the definition of exactly what I'm inheriting. And even though I do specify wrap_content for both layout_width and layout_height on a 32x32 ImageButton, for example, I get a much bigger button, clearly as a result of some set of settings within the theme I'm inheriting.

Comment: @Calaf I see what you mean and you are right android styling system needs a lot of documentation and clarification. Your best friend right now is the ...sdk\platforms\android-xx\data\res folder in your sdk installation and some guiding from the internet [I started with this](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/09/creating-custom-android-styles-easy-way.html). Good luck with styling :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use your own colors just create your own theme and set it to that instead of `AppTheme`

Comment: The question is: What do I stand to lose if I use no themes?

Answer (score 0):

As when using the `style` attribute directly inside `HTML` you won't be able to re-use styling in different views, unless you write the same styles to every view you want it in.

It's easier just to write your own theme and supply this to the views/`activities` you want to have the custom theme/styles.

What I'm getting at: you won't be able to control styling as easy if you're adding styling directly inside your views and `Activities` and it might be a mess to implement global styling later on as your application grows.

Also to quote the [official Android theming guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html):

> Styles in Android share a similar philosophy to cascading stylesheets in web design—they allow you to separate the design from the content.

And to answer your question: No you don't have to be worried. You can delete whatever you want, but it is discouraged not to use the styles.xml because aforementioned reasons.